# How to know application lifecycle from android library

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I am looking for a elegant way to monitor application's lifecycle as I am working on a SDK that needs to register some listeners. I would like to unregister the listener when the application goes to background or invisible and my library DOES NOT have any awareness of the lifecycle of the application.

For example, when the app goes to background, I want to stop sensorEvent by `unregister` the listener. However, I do not want to ask my consumer to explicitly call another method from my SDK to start/stop service from their host app level.

I thought of using `Lifecycle Arch Components` but it seems that I still need to ask consumer to call [`addObserver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Lifecycle.html#addObserver(android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver)) method on host level to observe. Moreover, my library is wrapped inside another SDK that may or may not have life cycle states either.

What's the better way for a general SDK to listen to life cycle event without asking host app level explicitly invoke register/unregister method?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Android Architecture Component's [`Lifecycle` module](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle)** to add lightweight *lifecycle awareness* to your own library/app.

In fact that is what the Support Library classes (like [`FragmentActivity`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/fragment/src/main/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java), etc.) depends on. More specifically, you just need to include the Lifecycle dependency to your library and that would just add the [`Lifecycle`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle) component without bloating your library with `Livedata` and `ViewModel`.

Now, using the `Lifecycle` component, you can do something like this:

```
// using commom-java8 module
public class Falcon implements DefaultLifecycleObserver {

  public Falcon(@NotNull LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner){
    // your initialization code

    lifecycleOwner.getLifecycle().addObserver(this); // register our instance
  }

  // Now you can selectively override lifecycle callbacks that you are
  // interested in and the Lifecycle component will take care of calling
  // them at appropriate time


  @Override public void onCreate(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner){
    // library logic here
  }      
}
```

Then, consumer of your library could do something like

```
public SpaceXDashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // usual code....

    Falcon falcon = new falcon(this /* LifecycleOwner */);
  }
}
```

And this way you can make your Android library aware of the lifecycle of the components while providing a significant abstraction from the actual component and also preventing memory leaks!

Note that this solution requires that you use the new Java 8 language support for Android and also it requires consumers of your library to use (atleast) version 26.1.0 of the SupportLibrary.

If you are unable to met any of the aforementioned constraint, you can also try the solution shown [on this Medium post](https://android.jlelse.eu/is-your-android-library-lifecycle-aware-127629d32dcc)

Comment: Please check out the question statement again that I dont really want to use `arch component` library as that still require extra code changes from host app level. Moreover, my caller may not have the lifecycle callback access.

Comment: Ahh.. If you take a look at the example `Activity` in the above post, it seems "quite natural" meaning there is _no extra code_ that your end user should have to write. The only requirement that I feel is that the end user must be using Java 8 and Support Library v26+ and there is [a workaround for that too!](https://android.jlelse.eu/is-your-android-library-lifecycle-aware-127629d32dcc). So IMO, if the library is already getting your job done then why don't use it?

Comment: "Moreover, my caller may not have the lifecycle callback access" - can you elaborate? Do you want to give access to lifecycle callbacks to your users or consume them yourself?

Comment: hi, sorry for the confusion. I did a quick try on your solution and it does work for part of the requirements. However, as I mentioned, my caller might not have access to `AppCompatActivity`. your `Falcon falcon = new falcon(this /* LifecycleOwner */);` relies on caller having the access to `this` lifecycleowner. What shall we do this without the access to lifecycleowner? Can we get it from `applicationContext`?

Comment: Android _only manages_ the lifecycle of _components_ that includes `Activity`, `Service`, `BroadcastReceiver` and `ContentProvider`. As per your comment, if the user doesn't have access to these, he/she should either provide them or they do not need lifecycle-awareness at all !! In short the whole concept of lifecycle revolves around these _components_ and if your are not directly interacting with them you don't need to worry about their lifecycle...

Comment: For example, have a look at how `Retrofit` works... it is an HTTP (or REST) library and doesn't actively interacts with the _Android components_ and so it doesn't provide any _lifecycle-awareness_ to HTTP calls... Similarly, if your library doesn't need to actively interact with the _Android components_ then you don't need _lifecycle-awareness_ at all!!!

Comment: my use case is to stop listeners from my library such as location listener...etc. In this case, i will need to ask them to pass down the reference then.

Comment: Why don't you ship an Android `Service` with your library and ask your user to `bindService()` to your `Service` this way you can get first-hand lifecycle  calls from the system without any additional requirement on your user's part (and without any extra library)???

Comment: In either case your user need atleast some way to instantiate your library since you cannot automagically start your library. I guess writing one-line--of-code is _not a big overhead_ and your concern is not valid here....

Answer (score 0):

Use [Activity Lifecycle Callbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks)). You could do something like provide a base `Application` class that does the register then the client app need only extend your `Application` base class.

I don't think there's a way to make it happen by having the client app simply include your lib. At the least there'd need to be some compile-time plugin that re-writes the client's byte code to call your code. I don't know exactly how you'd do that.